# If i redirected my website from "HTTPS" to "HTTP", will i still be getting a ranking boost?

Tags: seo, google-search, https, googlebot, http

Google announced that going HTTPS will give you a ranking boost. So i bought SSL certificate to boost my rank and redirected all "HTTP" to "HTTPS" from .htacess... then i realized that it's not compatible with my site.

Because of mixed content error cause the content must be served over HTTPS, but since I've flash gaming website i need to get requests from "HTTP" sites otherwise the games will not work.

So my question is... If i redirected my website from HTTPS --> HTTP, will i still be getting a ranking boost? or google will act like i didn't buy one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rankings gained from SSL is so minor that many see no difference however it's excellent for protecting the privacy of your website users.

But to answer your question... no you won't be rewarded if you redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. Why would you be rewarded for a site that is no longer SSL enabled?

Google does not index pages that redirect... they index the end result. So if you redirect HTTPS to HTTP, within a month... Google will de-index HTTPS and re-index the HTTP.